# How to include org.json.jar and org.json.* imports at a MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: java, json

How can i properly include org.json.jar and org.json.* imports at a MANIFEST.MF file?

I'm using **JDeveloper IDE**

My `PhillPlugin.class` java file imports the following:

- `org.json.JSONObject`
- `org.json.JSONException`

I have also imported the `org.json.jar` file in my Libraries

I'm combining all these to a final `.jar` file

---

This is my `MANIFEST.MF` file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Version: 10
Bundle-Name: PhillPlugin
Bundle-Activator: phillplugin.PhillPlugin
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",oracle.security.am.plugin,oracle.security.am.plugin.authn,oracle.security.am.plugin.impl,oracle.security.am.plugin.api,oracle.security.am.common.utilities.principal,oracle.security.idm,javax.security.auth
Bundle-SymbolicName: PhillPlugin
Class-Path: felix.jar, identitystore.jar, oam-plugin.jar, utilities.jar, org.json.jar
```

I have included `org.json.jar` at `Class-Path` entry

How do i include the imports at `Import-Package` entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.json` should be imported in `Import-Package`.

Like so `org.json;resolution:= optional,org.json.JSONObject;resolution:=optional`

Here is my manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: PhillPlugin
Bundle-Version: 10
Bundle-Name: PhillPlugin
Bundle-Activator: phillplugin.PhillPlugin
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",oracle.security.am.
 plugin,oracle.security.am.plugin.authn,oracle.security.am.plugin.impl
 ,oracle.security.am.plugin.api,oracle.security.am.common.utilities.pr
 incipal,oracle.security.idm,javax.security.auth,org.json;resolution:=
 optional,org.json.JSONObject;resolution:=optional
```